# HTML5 properly nesting header tag

Tags: html, header

How am I meant to use a header tag, when it can't nest properly in my layout? EG:

```
<body>

<header>

<div class="topBar"></div>
<div class="mainBox">
    <div class="headWrapper">       
        <div class="searchWrap">
            <label for="SearchBox">Search Scirra</label>
            <input type="text" name="SearchBox" id="SearchBox" tabindex="1" />
            <div class="s searchIco"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Logo placeholder -->       
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul class="mainMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="mainSelected">Construct</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Arcade</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Manual</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="underMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#">Construct</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="underSelected">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Community Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </header>

    <div class="contentWrapper">
        <div class="wideCol">
                 Content!  Whee whee!  Elephants are powerful!  Elephants are strong!
                 *SNIP REST OF DOCUMENT THAT FLOWS FROM HERE*
```

Semantically this is correct, but it's not nested correctly, am I doing it wrong/right?  Do I  need to change my document structure?  Am I being pedantic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `<div class="mainBox">` is not closed.  It needs to close before the header closes.

Comment: I snipped it out, sorry I didn't make it clear.  It encompases a lot of the page, the head and the content.

Comment: If what you said is true, then the page is not semantically correct. If div.mainbox starts within your header tag, it must also close before your header tag closes. If .mainbox is supposed to be a container for the entire page, then it should start before the header tag, not inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you currently using to test your HTML5? Depending on the browser what you are trying to do might simply not work.

A valid HTML5 page could look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>HTML5!</h1>
      </header>
      <p>
        lalalal bla bla bla!
      </p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not a html5 format because you put <header> tag instead of <head> tag on the title & you not closed the <section></section> use have to check this link
 http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/html5-page-structure/

Comment: <header> tag instead of <head>?